# Qt QGraphicsView and StyleSheets

Tags: c++, css, qt, qgraphicsview

Can I use CSS/stylesheets to style a item in QGraphicsView, like QGraphicsWidget?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's directly possible, at least if you apply a stylesheet to the `QGraphicsView` itself it will not affect any widgets inside of it. However, you can assign a stylesheet to a widget before adding it into the scene, then it will keep it's style after being added:

```
QGraphicsScene scene;
QPushButton b;

b.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{background-color:red}");
scene.addWidget(&b);

QGraphicsView view(&scene);
view.show();
```

Comment: Ok, that is a nice trick. But I think I'm right when I say that none of the "GraphicsView-based" objects (Not old-school Widgets) have a setStyleSheet method. So they their look should be defined using Pallets and drawn using a QPainter in a overridden Paint function.